# Running a subset of docker commands without sudo

Tags: docker

Currently, if you add your user to the `docker` group you can run all docker commands without sudo. However, I only want to let the user run a subset of docker commands (namely, the read-only commands such as `inspect`, `ps`, `stats`, `images`, etc).

Is there a way to create a second group that behaves similarly?

Currently, I am using sudoers file to restrict the user to the above mentioned commands. But the user still has to type sudo.

Docker version 1.12.1 on CentOs 7.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict users to have only access to a limited sets of commands, you can either use an [Authorization plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/) (code examples can be found in the [https://github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers](https://github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers/tree/master/authorization) repository on GitHub, and a more complete example [here](https://github.com/projectatomic/docker-novolume-plugin)), or use a proxy server that prevents access to API endpoints that you don't want your users to have access to.

Keep in mind that `docker run` (even without `--privileged`), allows access to the host's filesystem.